# laravel 4 route post throw new NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, http-post, laravel-routing

I am reading codebright. Try on the data retrieval part. But I got failed on routing.

I install my laravel on wamp.

Here is my code.

form.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="baz" value="boo" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('/', function() {
    $data = Input::all();
    var_dump($data);
});


Route::get('post-form', function() {
    return View::make('form');
});
```

It showed an error page and said "`throw new NotFoundHttpException;`"

But after I add a trailing slash to action. like this: `"action={{url('/')/}}"`. It works fine. I don't know where is wrong. `.htaccess` or I need to set `virtual machine`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But using Route::get is okay. But using Route::post() was failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your Routes : 
lets say you have route '/ '

in your routes file 
`Route::get('/',array('as'=>'Home');`
Home is the Name of the Routes

go to form in blade and
    $url = URL::route('Home');//$url is you Route

```
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'post','action'=>$url))}}
```

check 
[Laravel-docs-Named_Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after I did that. It still show error. I think the problem caused by trailing slash. Because I added '/' at the end of action and everything's fine.

Comment: THX. I found the problem. It should be return var_dump($data). Sorry for my stupid question.